# Stop laptop from resuming from sleep by opening the lid

Tags: laptop, sleep, windows-8.1, wake-up, lid

I'm using a Dell Inspiron N411z. When I open the lid, the laptop automatically resumes from sleep.

I don't want this behaviour. I want to manually press the power button to wake it up. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: cut the wire to the sensor that determines if the lid is open or closed?

Comment: that's too extreme

Comment: I have the same question for a Thinkpad T440S, running Windows 10